# How to record audio from microphone input using TMediaPlayer in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, audio, audio-recording

Hi I'm quite new  to Delphi but have programmed before.

I want to record audio from a laptop's microphone input. Tmediaplayer has a record button but I can't quite understand the documentation from 
  http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/MPlayer_TMediaPlayer_StartRecording.html  on how to use it.

Could someone please list some steps on how to use it or link any example code where Tmediaplayer is used for recording?

Also what format is the recorded file saved? Can it be an array with the data within it or is it a .WAV file?

Any help appreciated and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use is pretty simple, using the [TMediaPlayer.OnClick](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.OnClick) event. This answer is based on the VCL.TMediaPlayer, as you've not specified which UI library you're using.

```
procedure TForm1.MediaPlayer1Click(Sender: TObject; Button: TMPBtnType;
  var DoDefault: Boolean);
begin
  case Button of
    btStop:
      begin
        MediaPlayer1.Stop;
        MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'WhateverYouWant.wav';
        MediaPlayer1.Save;
      end;
    btRecord: MediaPlayer1.StartRecording;
  end;
```

I've omitted the other buttons for brevity.

The file type is determined by the [TMediaPlayer.DeviceType](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMPDeviceTypes) property, which has to be set before the recording is started. The only audio recording type I can see in the list is the WAV format.

Comment: Oh right, thanks a lot @Ken White! I have  Delphi® 2007 for Win32, does that use the same library as mentioned above? However, the buttons are disabled on the form. Therefore, what  value is changed for the case statement? Do I have to create  separate buttons and then in there event handler add this code?

Comment: Yes, it's the same component. I can't tell you why the buttons are disabled on the form; I don't have that issue. Do you have a sound card (for playback) and a microphone (for recording) configured on your system?

Comment: In 'Object inspector' I made the option 'autoopen' to true. This enabled some buttons such as play, record, rewind and fast forward. However the the stop button is disabled. Yes it's on my laptop , in which the soundcard is working and I have plugged in a microphone to record. I have literally added tmediaplayer to my form and then used the above code (once I created an click event for it). I'm not sure why the stop button does not work. @KenWhite

Comment: The stop button is disabled because you can't stop until you've started (which should make perfect sense to you), just like you can't start when you're already playing or recording.

Comment: oh okay thanks. Yes when I press record it still does not come so there is no way to stop recording.I guess I will just try and figure it out. Thanks for the help so far. @KenWhite

Comment: I don't have a way to record from the system I'm working on now, so unfortunately I can't look into this for you. I'll try to remember to do so later, when I'm at a different machine.